# iOS/Swift - Tapping on tableview cell doesn't do anything

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My app is essentially a `UITableView` of `UITableView`s. But when I click on a cell, nothing happens for some reason. The cell just gets grayed out. I'm unsure why this happens. I've spent the last 2 hours trying to figure it out but I just can't find the problem.

My appologies if this turns out to be such a silly problem. I'm new to iOS development.

The full project can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1GgS8Pwx4SBZjg3YjduejBPemc

I reckon the files which are relevant are

- `Main.storyboard`
- `MasterViewController.swift`
- `IntermediateViewController.swift`

A little description: The app is meant to save your favorite twitter search queries. Essentially, each tag maps to a certain query. When you click on a tag, you get a `UITableView` of tweets returned by searching twitter API with that query. I haven't yet defined what happens when you click on a tweet, but a double click brings up a `UIAlertController` so that you can reply to that tweet. A long press follows that user.

None of this is relevant, though. The problem is in the `UITableView` to `UITableView` transition thats triggered when you click on a cell.

Places of interest:

MasterViewController.swift:

- `prepareForSegue()`
- Callback methods

Main.Storyboard:

- Segues and structure

Any help would be appreciated. I've stretched myself out trying to figure out what's the problem. Please describe the problem when you see it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the table view's `delegate` and `dataSource` properties? Did you implement the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method?

Comment: Why are you putting table views in a table view? Why not use one table view with sections?

Comment: have u used didselectrowatindexpath delegate method?

Comment: @rmaddy 1) I'm not sure what you mean by the delegate and dataSource properties. What should the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method do? All I do is call the super version. 2) It doesn't make much sense to implement the app that way.

Comment: @iAnurag I've tried calling the super version of the method, and excluding it fully, and both exhibit the same behavior. No custom code is included under didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform a segue when a cell is selected. In your tableView controller in the following method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

create and present the other view controller using :

```
self.presentViewController(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController,
                  animated flag: Bool,
                completion completion: (() -> Void)?)
```

And if you've created the segue in the storyboard, you should set the segue identifier in the Storyboard to `"showDetail"` as indicated in `prepareForSegue` in `MasterViewController.swift`

Comment: Oh, I missed that. But that doesn't seem to change the behavior of the app. I've even removed the if conditional alltogether and it still exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Everything works great now. Thank you, you're awesome!

Comment: You should accept the answer that fixed your problem